# apollo writeQuery does not work

Tags: caching, local, store, graphql, apollo

i have a problem with local apollo  modification like this:

```
     `updateBoth: (schema, value) =>
       client.writeQuery({
         query: queryObject,
         variables: { id },
         data: {
           Object: {
             ...obj,
             value,
             objectSchema: {
               ...obj.objectSchema,
               structure: schema,
             },
           },
         },
       }),`
```

i am struggling greatly anybo can help me?
it does not update value (this time but generally acts bad in many situations)